# Collision detection, make object move through a perfectly sized passage?

Tags: java, libgdx

Here is my movement code

```
float d45 = (float) (1 / Math.sqrt(2));
        float moveX, moveY;
        switch (direction) {
        case NORTH:
            moveX = 0;
            moveY = 1;
            break;
        case SOUTH:
            moveX = 0;
            moveY = -1;
            break;
    // [...] and so on [...]
        case SOUTHEAST:
            moveX = d45;
            moveY = -d45;
            break;
        default:
            moveX = 0;
            moveY = 0;
            break;
        }

        float t = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

         moveX = moveX * t * speed;
         moveY = moveY * t * speed;
```

then here is the code that detects collision and moves my object which I call Stuff

```
for (Stuff s : collidables) {
            if (overlaps(s, moveX, 0)) { //checks X collision
                collidedX.add(s);
                x += moveX > 0 ? s.x - width - x : s.x + s.width - x;
            }
        }
        if (collidedX.size < 1) {
            x += moveX;
        }
        for (Stuff s : collidables) { //checks Y collision
            if (overlaps(s, 0, moveY)) {
                collidedY.add(s);
                y += moveY > 0 ? s.y - height - y : s.y + s.height - y;
            }
        }
        if (collidedY.size < 1) {
            y += moveY;
        }
```

If I zoom in my camera so the pixels are HUGE then I can move my object through the passage. But if I zoom out at my normal 1920x1080 resolution no matter how much I hold my up and right arrow keys I can't get it through the perfect fit passage. How can I make it so it will slip through this perfect size passage?

EDIT I have more information
it has to do with the fact that I am ending up with fractions of pixels. If I cast the float x and y to an int it is more likely to line up and fit through the passage but it is still moving too fast most of the time to make it through as I push upright for example. I guess this is more of a how do I compensate for a small perfect fit passageway than an exact code error.

Comment: If you have any further questions about my code please comment here and I will add a comment to my code to explain further.

Comment: I suggest you use `double` for your calculations.  It will make the code simpler and possibly more accurate.  Your description isn't clear enough.  Your code is the one which doesn't allow you to do what you want.  I suggest you debug the code to determine why it doesn't work the way you want.

Comment: @PeterLawrey libGDX already seems to use float for everything which is why I kept going along with it. Everything works fine, with one exception. If I push up right to move up right for example and slide across a smooth surface leading to a passageway (is this image clear to you?) then it slides right over the passageway. UNLESS I make the spacing about 10 pixels. Sort of like how super mario can run over a surface that is thin enough without falling through the cracks. In this case though I want to make sure it slips through the small passage.

Comment: Ok, I suggest you setup a unit test which creates this scenario and checks your code performs as expected.  Then you can see why the code doesn't do what you expected in your debugger.

Comment: @PeterLawrey right now I have it set up like your saying and I have it debugging. I'm just a little confused as to what exactly is causing the problem because it is so precise and everything seems to be working perfectly. Any particular variable you think might be causing the problem or section?

Comment: Something at some point is not working perfectly or there wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I think I might have to draw you a picture to see exactly what is going on. I figured it out, I am moving fractions of pixels and it just so happens they are hardly ever lining up. When I have a 10 pixel wide square and the passage way is only 10 pixels wide I keep lining up just a fraction of a pixel off. Somehow I need to detect this passage way as I am moving left and right. But I am not sure how. Like lets say I line up the square with the passageway it will go right through. This is only an issue for very small spaces though.

Comment: Sometimes making the code completely realistic doesn't mean it is the most playable. Perhaps a small tolerance is a better option.